# JNA BaseAddress / find dylib

Tags: java, macos, dll, jna, dylib

I got my own kind of MacProcess with taskID, pid and the name. Actually I want to get all modules/dylibs of this process with their address (or just a specific one with a name e.g client.dylib)

On windows I can do something like that:

```
 public int base(String dllName) {
    Pointer snap = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32.intValue() | Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPMODULE.intValue(), getProcessId("processname"));
    Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W entry = new Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W.ByReference();
    while (kernel32.Module32NextW(snap, entry)) {
        String name = entry.szModule();
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(dllName + ".dll")) {
            Pointer pointer = entry.hModule.getPointer();
            return ((Long) Pointer.nativeValue(pointer)).intValue();
```

But on MacOS I obviously can't use the dlls and so on. How I can get the address with JNA of a module (e.g test.dylib) of a running application on my Mac? So actually a module (e.g client.dylib) with it´s address from a running application. For better understanding what I am looking for I added this code for windows. Thank you very much for your time & help!

Comment: This is more of an OSX/BSD question than JNA.  Once you figure out how to do it in native code, then you can simply map those calls into JNA.  You might start with `dyld` and `dyldinfo`.

Comment: While not identical to OSX/BSD, the general idea [is described here](http://syprog.blogspot.ru/2011/12/listing-loaded-shared-objects-in-linux.html).

Comment: @technomage Thank you very much! I figured out the native method in c, but I have no idea of how I can map these calls into JNA. Can you provide an example or you have a simple guide/documentation concerning this topic? In the method are things like 
    void getModule(task_t task, mach_vm_address_t * start, off_t * length ...  How I can transform this method into JNA? Thank you very much!

Comment: Include the native definitions/usage in your question, as well as whatever mappings you've tried thus far.  You'll likely have to look up the definition fo things like `task_t` and `mach_vm_address_t`, although sometimes you can get away with simply using a `Pointer` if the structure is opaque.